# Bootstrap Modal Reactivity With Livewire

Tags: bootstrap-4, laravel-livewire

I use bootstrap 4 modal for my laravel 8 and livewire project,
the problem is the reactivity of wire:model didn't work,

**app-layout :**

```
    {{ $modal ?? '' }}

    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    @livewireScripts
</body>
</html>
```

Livewire Controller :

```
class Table extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    
    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';

    public $excel = 'hello';
    
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.budgets.table', [
            'budgets' => Budget::with('owner')->simplePaginate(5)
        ]);
    }
}
```

index.blade.php (laravel components) :

```
<x-app-layout title="Budget">
    <x-slot name="description">
        You can create, modify,  and review your budget plan here.
    </x-slot>
    
    <livewire:budgets.table />
</x-app-layout>
```

table.blade.php (livewire components) :

```
    <div>
<button class="btn btn-success mr-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#excelModal">Excel</button>
    <x-slot name="modal">
        {{-- Budget Modal --}}
        <x-modal title="Budget Modal" id="budgetModal">
            Budget Modal
        </x-modal>

        {{-- Excel Modal --}}
        <x-modal title="Excel Modal" id="excelModal">
            Excel Modal
            <input type="text" class="form-control" wire:model="excel">
            {{ $excel }}
        </x-modal>
    </x-slot>
    </div>
```

modal.blade.php (Laravel component) :

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" {{ $attributes }}>
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">{{ $title }}</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            {{ $slot }}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer bg-whitesmoke br">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what's the issue? try this

```
{{-- Excel Modal --}}
<x-modal title="Excel Modal" id="excelModal" wire:ignore.self>
   Excel Modal
   <input type="text" class="form-control" wire:model.lazy="excel">
   {{ $excel }}
</x-modal>

// in component

public function updatedExcel($value)
{
  dd($value);
}
```

Comment: yep, the wire:ignore.self had solved my problem , thanks !

Comment: This could do with an explanation of what exactly `wire:ignore.self` is and why it solved the problem.

Comment: Well, simply read the docs... https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/reference#template-directives\